# Exception during the start of Saiku

Tags: java, exception, ioexception, saiku

Im getting the below exception during the startup of Saiku.

```
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.saiku.web.service.SessionService   
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.saiku.web.service.SessionService
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for this?